# Loading a Taskbar Icon from resources and using Prism to inject view model

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, notifyicon

### Background

I am trying to write an application which primarily lives on the system tray, it will in the future have a window so on right clicking the icon it opens the window.

### The Code

I currently have no shell being defined on Prism startup i.e.:

```cs
protected override Window CreateShell()
{
    return null;
}
```

The notify icon (using `Hardcodet.NotifyIcon` if that makes any difference?) is defined in a resources dictionary, as i don't have a startup *View* xaml to add the icon to:

```
<!-- the application's NotifyIcon - started from App.xaml.cs. Declares its own view model. -->
    <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Key="NotifyIcon"
                    IconSource="{Binding UserStatus, Converter={StaticResource UserStatusToImageSourceConverter}}"
                    ToolTipText="Double-click for window, right-click for menu"
                    DoubleClickCommand="{Binding ShowWindowCommand}"
                    ContextMenu="{StaticResource SysTrayMenu}">

         <!--self-assign a data context (could also be done programmatically)--> 
        <tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
            <viewModels:NotifyIconViewModel />
        </tb:TaskbarIcon.DataContext>
    </tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

The view model, as you can see on the later part of that snippet, takes the `NotifyIconViewModel`, which has a constructor argument so I can use the `IEventAggregator` to communicate between the different parts of views (like a view in the context menu shown when you just plain click on the tray icon).

The signature of the view model looks like so:

```
public NotifyIconViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
{
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    ...
}
```

The services are registered:

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
    ...
    containerRegistry.Register<NotifyIconViewModel>();
}
```

And the Notify Icon itself is instantiated in the `OnInitialized` Method:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    notifyIcon = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("NotifyIcon");
}
```

### The Issue

However, the exception being thrown on startup is that no default constructor could be found for the view model (correct, there isnt one). But my reading is that the prism architecture should be able to inject the view model (and its deps) when required?

[image: XamlParseException]

I can only assume I am initializing the notify icon incorrectly and that FindResource does not cause the prism library constructor injection/DI parts to be triggered, but what would the correct way for this behaviour to be carried out be?

Comment: `<viewModels:NotifyIconViewModel />` is your constructor call... I don't see any parameters here

Comment: ok, interesting and valid point, so how does one do this properly/correctly, given i have no parameter here for the IEventAggregator? How else should I tie the view model to the view component/icon to enable this auto-injection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependencies are injected if you use the container to construct (aka. resolve) the object.

This happens when a normal Prism application resolves the shell, which (by using the `ViewModelLocator`) resolves the shell's view model which resolves alle the dependencies of the shell's view model and the dependencies of those dependencies and so on.

If you do *not* use the container (i.e. by constructing objects directly in xaml), it won't resolve any dependencies for you.

You could create the icon and use the container to resolve the `NotifyIconViewModel` and set it as `DataContext`:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    notifyIcon = (TaskbarIcon)FindResource("NotifyIcon");
    notifyIcon.DataContext = Container.Resolve<NotifyIconViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: well hot dawg! that worked! great work around and makes total sense when you point out above in the comments that the call has no args! now to go through the fun of regions..